# http request validation and then redirection using HAProxy

Tags: validation, http, proxy, lua, haproxy

I am trying to build a middleware using HAProxy. 
Following is my usecase:
1. I need to capture all the incoming request to HAProxy and send it to a REST API for validation.
2. capture validation response, and if validation response is OK I need to add some headers to the original request and send it back to another set of REST APIs.

Step 1:
Original Request ---> HAProxy --Req--> Validation API

Step 2:
Validation API --(Response)--> HAProxy

Step 3(If validation successful):
HAProxy --(Req + SomeHeaders)--> OTHER Rest Services

I have tried playing around with HAProxy configuration and HAProxy + Lua integration, but unfortunately I am not able to achieve the functionality I need.

Also, if you have used, please feel free to suggest any other tool or point me to the right resources thanks!

Comment: This application seems outside the scope of HAProxy to me.  To a limited extent it could be hacked with Lua but it would require a lot of manual HTTP manipulation with string and regex matching, and forwarding the request to the intermediate endpoint using a raw Lua TCP socket.  The request headers and body would have to fit into a single HAProxy request buffer (default 16KB). I think it's "possible" but with difficulty and the solution could feel fragile. I would be inclined to use a web framework that makes more of the HTTP handling as transparent as you want it to be, such as Mojolicious.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Let me try a few things with Mojolicious and Lua hacks as well. I am just wondering about the performance with Lua script hack will it able to maintain the agility and speed of HAProxy? Which is the prime reason we want to use it.

Comment: Performance is something I perceive as one potential problem, though I admit it's perception and not something for which I can cite benchmarks.  Lua is lightweight but intuituvely won't perform as well as the HAProxy core, and the string manipulation seems costly.  I've toyed with it quite a bit, to the point of being the first to discover and report some early bugs (which were of course fixed).   I *completely* agree with the desire to keep it all inside HAProxy -- it's light, tight, and has screaming fast performance.

Comment: I've toyed with the idea of writing an async memcached over TCP client for HAProxy in Lua to do lookups during request processing, but have not yet convinced myself that it will be something I'll be comfortable using in production... so I have a but of writers' block.  You can use existing Lua modules as long as they don't do any I/O, because if they do, they'll block HAProxy processing other requests -- you have to use the HAProxy/Lua socket model to use TCP connections in Lua functions and you have to use IP addresses to connect, not hostnames, because there is no async DNS lookup available.

Comment: Thanks Mike. One quick question: I actually tried writing a lua script to achieve the intermediate connection through "socket.http" of lua, but I am getting the issue while running it with HAProxy. Here is the error that i'm getting: runtime error: error loading module 'socket.core' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so':
        /usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so: undefined symbol: lua_gettop

Any idea how to solve this error?
Same function is running just fine in lua shell. I'm using lua=5.3 and haproxy=1.6.2

Comment: I doubt that you can use `socket.http` here.  Like I say above, I believe you have to use the non-blocking socket API provided in the HAProxy/Lua integration.  Also, stop what you are doing and upgrade to HAProxy 1.6.11.  The Lua integration was not stable in 1.6.2 and there were some breaking changes and behavioral inconsistencies in the Lua interface between then and now.

Comment: I have pretty much tried everything. I did not find any example or resource on the web as well. I looked at the documentation
http://www.arpalert.org/src/haproxy-lua-api/1.7dev/#socket-class
But again its not of much help. Could you please point me to some resource which explain how to use haproxy/lua socket API? I will also try upgrading it to 1.6.11

Comment: Like I say... it's a low level/raw operation.  I'll look for an example I've written of doing an http request using Lua.

Comment: Well, I just upgraded HAProxy to 1.7.2 and its working just fine thanks for pointing the broken behavior of 1.6.2